# CSS Bullet List - Default bullets showing except image bullets

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm having the following problems. I'm trying to apply custom styles to my bulleted lists. 
However, after applying list-style-image property image is showing but also default bullet is showing as well.
Is there any way to hide it?

```css
.text ul {
  list-style-type: none !important;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

.text ul li {
  list-style-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/32x32") !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <ul>
    <li>Nam ac posuere metus. Vestibulum eleifend elementum mauris id aliquet. Morbi fermentum tempus velit, sit amet faucibus velit rhoncus vitae. Aenean efficitur a nibh vitae vulputate.</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
    <li>Nam ac posuere metus. Vestibulum eleifend elementum mauris id aliquet.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah adding ``list-style-type: none`` should work

Comment: I just checked it and it is working fine for me. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Actually it didn't. What I encountered in dev tools is that the default bullets come from 'user agent stylesheet; and this settings is overriding my list-type-style rule. I think it happens in all browsers - I checked Chrome, Edge and Safari

Comment: Would you also show the code for html mark up?

Comment: html code is `<ul>
<li>Nam ac posuere metus. Vestibulum eleifend elementum mauris id aliquet. Morbi fermentum tempus velit, sit amet faucibus velit rhoncus vitae. Aenean efficitur a nibh vitae vulputate.</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum</li>
<li>Nam ac posuere metus. Vestibulum eleifend elementum mauris id aliquet.</li>
</ul>`

Comment: Huh..!, I see you have added the style tag to .text ul and the code you are writing is directly as ul, that could be the problem.

Comment: This clearly works **provided** your `ul` has a parent with the class of `.text`.

Comment: it works properly on my machine and remove !important from inside style tag it  works fine

Comment: It seems fine to me also